# iPhone simulator is on the fritz

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, simulator

I wrote an app that saves the users inputted text, and it ran perfectly on the iPhone and iPad simulator. I closed Xcode, reopened it an hour later to double check it before I submit it, and ran into a weird issue. The app still runs perfectly on the iPad simulator, but on the iPhone simulator, it won't save the data anymore. Also, when I just close the app, then reopen it from the multitasking bar, it crashes. It was running perfectly on both simulators an hour ago, and I didn't change anything at all. I also restored a snapshot I took earlier when I was 100% sure it worked perfect after thorough testing, but the same issue is still occurring.

I think my iPhone simulator is on the fritz. If there was truly an issue with it, it would have the same effect on the iPad simulator, right? Has anyone else run into this issue? I already reset my computer and erased the simulators content and settings, didn't seem to work though.

Comment: You may need to look cloesly at what's happening & provide more info. In the meantime if you haven't already try quitting the simulator, run Clean & then run your app letting Xcode re-launch the simulator.

Comment: What is the issue? What is the crash? If it's a memory corruption issue it may work sometimes and not work other times, with no recognizable pattern.

Comment: That is all the information that the Simulator seemed to provide. I "Stopped" running the apps in Xcode, and then ran them on the simulator alone, because every time I hit the home button with the iPhone, I get an error in Xcode. It's the generic "Program received signal SIGABRT" in my main.m file. It doesn't have this error when I hit the home button on the iPad simulator at all though. I have already quit the sim, cleaned and reran. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Can you see if it gets to applicationWillResignActive: and then applicationDidEnterBackground: in the application delegate before it crashes? Put a break point at the entry point of those methods and tell us what happens.

Comment: SIGABRT is not a generic error. It's a specific error. You are raising an exception or an assertion. That's why you get an error in Xcode and why it appears to crash when not connected to Xcode (because it is, in fact, crashing with an un-handled exception). What is the exception?

Comment: Thanks. I put a breakpoint next to applicationDidEnterBackground: in AppDelegate.m, and it said "Thread 1: Stopped at breakpoint 1." Possibly related, I put my applicationDidEnterBackground: methods in my multiple ViewController.m files that I set up for each NIB. Could that be the issue?  And for the SIGABRT error, I'm researching what the exception is now. How could I tell what it is? I'm still a beginner sorry for the dumb question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIApplication delegate methods only belong in the application delegate, and it should be implementing the UIApplicationDelegate protocol methods, [as explained in the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

If you want other class objects to do something after applicationWillResignActive is started, you can put some code inside that method to make that happen. [Here is a link to a suggestion on how to do that](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/57685-applicationdidenterbackground-only-works-appdelegate-class.html). Why do you have applicationDidEnterBackground: methods inside other classes? This may be related to your problem, and should be easy enough to fix.

Comment: Thank you very much Jim. I move everything around and give that a shot. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. Come back for more help it you need it. I'm signing off for awhile.